# Simulation - Voxel Grid

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory, voxel

I'm trying to build a simulation that will take place in a 1000x1000x1000 space. For each point in space, I need to be able to encode 2 or 3 properties.

I also need to be able to do some basic operations on the space, such as, given a point, find the properties of the 26 adjacent 3D neighbors of the point.

All points will lie on vertices in the 1000x1000x1000 space (i.e. every point is discrete).

I wrote up a version in python using numpy and it is much too slow. I've also looked for libraries that would speed it up but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know of a python library that would provide useful helper functions and would be appropriate for a simulation of this size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Numpy` to together with the [`Numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) python-compiler for the more intricate algorithms can take you a long way.

Also, I think you are refering to a "stencil" algorithm, and `numba` has specific [stencil-functionality](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/stencil.html) that could help you.

But start with a smaller grid during development!